# PsExec hangs intermittently when calling AppCmd

Tags: iis, batch-file, team-foundation-server, pstools, appcmd

We have an automated deployment process which is primarily managed by a batch file. One of the first steps in that process is to stop an IIS AppPool so the updated files can be safely copied. To do this, we call PsExec, like this:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula %WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME% cmd /c %%systemroot%%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe stop apppool /apppool.name:"%APP_POOL_NAME%" 2>&1
```

Where the environment variables are (these are not the actual values, just for illustration):

- `WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME=\\WEBSERVER01`
- `APP_POOL_NAME=APP01`

The entire deployment process usually takes just a few minutes. However, it seems that sometimes, seemingly at random, this process gets stuck at this step and seems to wait indefinitely. If I check the web server during this process, `AppPool` is not stopped, and manually stopping the `AppPool` has no effect. There are 6 different sites that need to be deployed and this can happen on any one of the sites.

I have also tried disabling auto-start like this:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula %WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME% cmd /c %%systemroot%%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe set apppool /apppool.name:"%APP_POOL_NAME%" /autoStart:false 2>&1
```

And occasionally, but it seems to get stalled at this step sometimes. So, it seems to be an issue with `PsExec` rather than `AppCmd`. I have also tried specifying a connection timeout to `PsExec` as well as chaining an exit at the end of the `cmd` call, like this:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula -n 60 %WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME% cmd /c %%systemroot%%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe stop apppool /apppool.name:"%APP_POOL_NAME%" ^& exit 0 2>&1
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What could cause this `PsExec` call to stall intermittently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WMIC seems more reliable (though not perfect). Here's what I ended up using:

```
wmic /node:"%WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME%" /namespace:\\root\WebAdministration path ApplicationPool where name='%APP_POOL_NAME%' call start

wmic /node:"%WEB_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME%" /namespace:\\root\WebAdministration path ApplicationPool where name='%APP_POOL_NAME%' set AutoStart=true
```